# How to Update customer Attribute and which table it will be stored?

Tags: magento-2.1

I treid to create customer attribute programatically and now i want to update that the attribute with different label and type . I want to know in which table it will stored . I want to remove that attribute also.

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context)

    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'phone_number',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Mobile',
                'input'        => 'integer',
                'required'     => true,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $eavSetup->updateAttribute('customer', 'phone_number', 'type', 'varchar');
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'phone_number');     
       $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create']

        );

        $attribute->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The attribute itself stored `eav_attribute` table. 
please check with following SQL in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` where attribute_code='phone_number';
```

And the values are store in `customer_entity_varchar` table.

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity_varchar` where attribute_id=ID_OF_ATTRIBUTE_FROM_EAV_TABLE
```

If you want to upadte your Attribute then you need to add upgrade script. You cannot simply add in install script. Here is how upgrade script look like in app/code/VENDOR/MODULE/Setup/UpgradeData.php file:

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Setup;


use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //handle all possible upgrade versions

        if (!$context->getVersion()) {
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.0') < 0) { //VERSION OF YOUR MODULE in module.xml
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute $attribute */
            $attribute = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute');
            $attributeId = $attribute->getIdByCode('customer','phone_number');

            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                1,
                $attributeId,
                'type',
                'varchar'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns empty set

Comment: Then your attributes was not created at all. If it has been created then it should be seen in eav table

Comment: can you help me to how to do that ???

Answer (score 0):

The customer attribute you have created is stored in the table *customer_entity_varchar* as you had declared in your code with the "**type**" property.
Another reference to that attribute is going to be stored at *customer_entity* with the *entity_id* as a reference.

Comment: select * from  customer_entity_varchar ; returns empty set

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that worked for me was to use the getConnection function in an upgrade data script like this:

```
$setup->startSetup();

if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.8', '<'))
{

$attribute_id = $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode('customer', 'attribute_code');
$setup->getConnection()->update($setup->getTable('eav_attribute'),
['is_required' => false], 'attribute_id=' . $attribute_id);
}

$setup->endSetup();
```